# Bind action to the tomcat pool event

Tags: java, multithreading, tomcat

I'm working on a web application that's running using Tomcat (it's very Tomcat-oriented, with inclusion of Tomcat jars on the development stage and so on), and i need to bind an action to an event of returning Tomcat thread to it's pool. Is there way to do it?

Alternatively, is there any Tomcat-related thread local logic (like in java ThreadLocal class), that will consider same thread that have been taken from tomcat pool, returned back and taken again as two different "threads"?